# Magnitude of a complex function

Tags: complex-numbers

I have a function 
$$H(e^{j\Omega}) = \frac{\cos\Omega + j\sin\Omega}{(\cos\Omega - a) + j\sin\Omega}$$
We are to take the magnitude of this function in order to sketch a graph. So I tried
$$\left|H(e^{j\Omega})\right| = \frac{\left|\cos\Omega + j\sin\Omega\right|}{\left|(\cos\Omega - a) + j\sin\Omega\right|}$$
$$= \frac{\sqrt{\cos^2\Omega + \sin^2\Omega}}{\sqrt{(\cos\Omega - a)^2 + \sin^2\Omega}}$$
which evaluates into 
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+a^2 -2a\cos\Omega}}$$

But the book says it is 
$$\frac{1}{1+a^2 -2acos\Omega}$$

How can I get the last answer from the one I got so far? :(

**EDIT**
Added screenshots from the book
[image]
[image]

Comment: your answer is correct. Maybe the book is giving the magnitude squared

Comment: You are perfectly correct. I should bet for one more typo in a textbook.

Comment: But that is Prof. Oppenheim's book and there are graphs drawn from that derived equation. :(